# strange behaviour of static method

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I load a js variable like this:

```
var message = '<%= CAnunturi.CPLATA_RAMBURS_INFO %>';
```

where the static string CPLATA_RAMBURS_INFO i put like:

```
public static string CPLATA_RAMBURS_INFO = "test";
```

I use it very well in this method.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var categoryParam = '<%= CQueryStringParameters.CATEGORY %>';
    var subcategoryParam = '<%= CQueryStringParameters.SUBCATEGORY1_ID %>';
    var message = '<%= CAnunturi.CPLATA_RAMBURS_INFO %>';

    function timedInfo(header) {
        $.jGrowl(message, { header: header });
    };
</script>
```

so the message appears.

I do not undersand, why, iso of "test", if i take the value from a static method,
ths use of message js var is no longer succesfull (the message no longer appears).

```
public static string CPLATA_RAMBURS_INFO = getRambursInfo();

public static string getRambursInfo()
{
   return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(PathsUtil.getRambursPlataFilePath());
}
```

EDIT:
Source Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var categoryParam = 'category';
    var subcategoryParam = 'subcategory1Id';
    var message = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu curabitur venenatis
```

viverra pellentesque tortor tempor, 
nam est suspendisse, aenean vestibulum, 
suspendisse eget metus aenean at dictum nulla. 
In luctus, neque porttitor suscipit nibh, aenean 
ut, commodo velit leo volutpat ullamcorper.
';

```
    function timedInfo(header) {
        $.jGrowl(message, { header: header });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Exactly what goes wrong? Is there an exception?

Comment: Can you view source after the page is generated and see what is displayed there?  Maybe then you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: The $.jGrowl should show a message. In the first case it shows it well, in the second, i see the content of message var in the source code, but the message is no longer shown...

Comment: Please show us the rendered Javascript source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file contains special characters (probably a newline or a `'`) that cause the rendered Javascript to contain a syntax error.

You need to escape the string using the [Anti-XSS Toolkit](http://antixss.codeplex.com/Wikipage), like this:

```
var message = '<%= AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(CAnunturi.CPLATA_RAMBURS_INFO) %>';
```

**EDIT**: If AntiXss doesn't help, try the following function:

```
public static void QuoteString(this string value, StringBuilder b) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return "";

    var b = new StringBuilder();
    int startIndex = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) {
        char c = value[i];

        // Append the unhandled characters (that do not require special treament)
        // to the string builder when special characters are detected.
        if (c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == '\"' || c == '\'' || c == '<' || c == '>' ||
            c == '\\' || c == '\n' || c == '\b' || c == '\f' || c < ' ') {
            if (b == null) {
                b = new StringBuilder(value.Length + 5);
            }

            if (count > 0) {
                b.Append(value, startIndex, count);
            }

            startIndex = i + 1;
            count = 0;
        }

        switch (c) {
            case '\r':
                b.Append("\\r");
                break;
            case '\t':
                b.Append("\\t");
                break;
            case '\"':
                b.Append("\\\"");
                break;
            case '\\':
                b.Append("\\\\");
                break;
            case '\n':
                b.Append("\\n");
                break;
            case '\b':
                b.Append("\\b");
                break;
            case '\f':
                b.Append("\\f");
                break;
            case '\'':
            case '>':
            case '<':
                AppendCharAsUnicode(b, c);
                break;
            default:
                if (c < ' ') {
                    AppendCharAsUnicode(b, c);
                } else {
                    count++;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    if (b == null) {
        b.Append(value);
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        b.Append(value, startIndex, count);
    }

    return b.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I;ve isntalled Axss from microsoft, import this: using Microsoft.Security.Application; but still it does not see it...do you know why?

Comment: Your string has newlines, which should be escaped by AntiXss.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign value to your variable in Page_Load() function. I think it'll work.

Comment: I mean this:

public static string CPLATA_RAMBURS_INFO;

void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CPLATA_RAMBURS_INFO = getRambursInfo();
}